# Can't see my Custom App Event (Facebook Analytics)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, analytics, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've integrated the Facebook SDK to my unity project, and I get the standard event every time I install or Launch the application.

The problem is that I tried to add a custom event and I can't track it. It does not appear in Facebook Analytics Event Debug.

```
public void LogStart_gameEvent()
{
    FB.LogAppEvent(
        "start_new_game"
    );
}
```

This method is called when the game start, but the event does not seems to be registred by Facebook Analytics.

Thanks,

NLP

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I've the same issue.